# Envelope for pooled mark correlation functions

Tags: r, spatstat

I wish to create an envelope for mark correlation functions (in my example, mark variogram, but this should apply to any of them) pooling field replicates from what's assumed to be the same point process. While having read the documentation available for each of those steps in isolation, I couldn't find much about the application of pooling and envelopes to mark correlation functions.
In the following I'll illustrate my attempt by recreating in an example, at the best of my abilities, with `longleaf` and a jittered copy of it (despite being meaningless, it should suffice).

```
longleaf2 <- rjitter(longleaf, radius=10, retry = T)

list <- solist(longleaf, longleaf2)

vario <- lapply(list, function(x) envelope(x, markvario, nsim = 39, 
                                           simulate=expression(rlabel(x)), savefuns=T))

pool <- pool(as.anylist(vario))
plot(pool)
```

While the output seems reasonable, I have no assurance about this procedure being sound. Additionally, while the envelope shading is plotted with this example, it's not with my data, and forcing it with `plot.envelope` returns an error.
Alternatively,  [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70152516/plotting-the-k-function-in-spatstat-seems-to-only-consider-single-data-and-not) seems to suggest pooling first, then making envelopes, but there's no `fv` method for `envelope` as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several questions here.

Firstly about the validity of pooling:

> While the output seems reasonable, I have no assurance about this procedure being sound.

Pooling several `envelope` objects involves extracting all the simulated functions from all the envelopes, and constructing a new `envelope` object based on these simulated functions. If that is valid in your context, then the procedure is valid.

Validity depends on how the simulated functions were generated. In your case, if there are several different point pattern datasets, and you generate an envelope for each data point pattern using `rlabel` to randomise the marks, then I think it is **not** valid to pool these envelopes, because the summary functions in one envelope are not exchangeable with the summary functions from another envelope.

Next about the computational procedure:

> Additionally, while the envelope shading is plotted with this example, it's not with my data, and forcing it with `plot.envelope` returns an error.

So... the example given in the question is working as desired,... but with your data it doesn't work? Please provide a minimal working example where the procedure does not work.

In your example, `vario` is a list, each element of which is an `envelope` object. Then the `pool` command is dispatched to `pool.anylist` which invokes `pool.envelope`. Then the result is an `envelope` object.

In your actual data (which you didn't show us) the first thing would be to check that you have a list of `envelope` objects, e.g.

```
all(sapply(vario, inherits, what="envelope"))
```

If this is `FALSE` then the result of `pool` will not be an envelope object.

Comment: If pooling envelopes based on `rlabel` isn't a valid approach in this case, is there a way to pool replicate observations for envelope testing with mark correlation functions, or is it only viable to pool envelopes based on duplicates of the same point pattern dataset?
I wished to give an example which was quick to reproduce. I have prepared a sample of the dataset to show the issue of the missing bands, but I don't know of a good way to upload it.
Anyway, the above test returns `TRUE` for my dataset.
I want to thank you also for continuing your impressive work even here, Prof. Baddeley.